# Bootstrap validator.js not communicating with my PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a novice coder, and i'm having trouble putting a simple form together using validator.js

Basically since trying to build in the validation the form has stopped working, my guess is the 'data: $('#send-form').serialize(),' has not got the correct path or syntax, but i could be wrong.

As soon as i add:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "process.php",
data: $('#send-form').serialize(),
}
```

the alerts do not fire!

```html
<form class="contact" name="contact" id="send-form" data-toggle="validator" role="form"  >


  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="subTitle" for="name">NAME</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your full name" data-error="Please enter your name" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div><br>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="subTitle" for="email">E-MAIL</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" data-error="Invalid email address" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div><br>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="subBtn form-control">SUBMIT YOUR ENQUIRY</button>
    </div>

</form> 




    



<script>
$('#send-form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        alert('form is not valid');
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('form is valid');
        // your ajax
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: $('#send-form').serialize(),
                }
});

</script>
```

Comment: maybe because you have syntax error?

Comment: you are missing a `);` after your ajax call and a `}` for the  else clause --> `$('#send-form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        alert('form is not valid');
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('form is valid');
        // your ajax
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: $('#send-form').serialize()
                });
   }
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
$('#send-form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        alert('form is not valid');
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('form is valid');
        // your ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: $('#send-form').serialize(),
        });
    }
});
```

(untested)

Comment: Yes a syntax error. Code now works online. Many thanks